# Using insert into ... select results in a incorrect syntax near select, why?

Tags: sql

How can I make a SELECT inside an INSERT operation?

```
insert into tableX (a_id, b_id) 
VALUES ((SELECT service_id 
         FROM tableY 
         WHERE id = 10, 2));
```

But the server returns a syntax error, why?

```
SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

While my original answer gave a working solution, I was actually wrong about the cause of the error.  There is nothing wrong with using a scalar subquery inside a VALUES clause.  The problem with the statement in the question is simply that one parenthesis is in the wrong place; the scalar subquery must be enclosed in parentheses.

This should work:

```
insert into tableX (a_id, b_id) 
VALUES (
  (SELECT service_id 
         FROM tableY 
         WHERE id = 10)
  , 2
  );
```

**Original Answer**

`VALUES` can only be used in conjunction with literal values.  However, literal values can be used in a subquery.  Do this:

```
insert into tableX (a_id, b_id) SELECT service_id, 2 FROM tableY WHERE id = 10
```

Answer (score 12):

You don't need the values key word and also you can add the default value 2 for b_id column in the select list instead of adding it after the SELECT statement

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tableX (a_id, b_id) 
SELECT service_id, 2 
  FROM tableY 
 WHERE id = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the `values` word.

here is some documentation for mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

also, when you specify the columns into which the values should be inserted, you need to make sure your select returns the same number/types appropriate to what you specified.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the DBMS that you're inserting two values (a_id, b_id) but only selecting one (service_id).

Comment: Not quite -- although his brackets are misplaced, I think the `,2` is meant to be the second value.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
insert into tableX (a_id, b_id)
SELECT service_id, 4 as QUESTIONMARK FROM tableY WHERE id in (10, 2);
```

This works on many database engines however we don't know what environment you are working on.

EDIT: What is the second insert supposed to be?

Answer (score -2):

In `MySQL` one can insert dynamic values. Here is the sample:

```
INSERT INTO Item_Info (`Back_Ground_Color`,) 
VALUES ( (select concat('#',SUBSTRING((lpad(hex(round(rand() * 10000000)),6,0)),-6))));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question